# Webpack logging lot of sockjs information

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, console.log, sockjs

I installed React project on another computer and suddenly console in browser is filled with these:

```
sockjs-client:websocket unload +96ms
browser.js:123 sockjs-client:main using url +0ms http://localhost:8080/sockjs-node
browser.js:123 sockjs-client:utils:url same +3ms http://localhost:8080/sockjs-node http://localhost:8080/category/PLvbS24bigqq80_SfZtLIF_1MUhSuVCOGY true
browser.js:123 sockjs-client:info-receiver http://localhost:8080/sockjs-node +1ms
log.js:5 [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
browser.js:123 sockjs-client:info-receiver doXhr +325ms http://localhost:8080/sockjs-node/info
browser.js:123 sockjs-client:browser:xhr GET +2ms http://localhost:8080/sockjs-node/info
browser.js:123 sockjs-client:browser:xhr readyState +157ms 2
browser.js:123 sockjs-client:browser:xhr readyState +1ms 3
browser.js:123 sockjs-client:browser:xhr status +1ms 200
browser.js:123 sockjs-client:browser:xhr chunk +0ms
browser.js:123 sockjs-client:browser:xhr readyState +3ms 4
browser.js:123 sockjs-client:browser:xhr status +1ms 200
browser.js:123 sockjs-client:browser:xhr finish +1ms 200 {"websocket":true,"origins":["*:*"],"cookie_needed":false,"entropy":3957747340}
browser.js:123 sockjs-client:info-receiver finish +2ms Object {websocket: true, origins: Array(1), cookie_needed: false, entropy: 3957747340} 166
browser.js:123 sockjs-client:info-receiver _cleanup +4ms
browser.js:123 sockjs-client:main _receiveInfo +1ms 166
browser.js:123 sockjs-client:main info +2ms Object {websocket: true, origins: Array(1), cookie_needed: false, entropy: 3957747340, nullOrigin: false…}
browser.js:123 sockjs-client:websocket enabled +2ms
browser.js:123 sockjs-client:utils:transport enabled +0ms websocket
browser.js:123 sockjs-client:utils:transport enabled +1ms xhr-streaming
browser.js:123 sockjs-client:utils:transport disabled +1ms xdr-streaming
browser.js:123 sockjs-client:utils:transport enabled +1ms eventsource
browser.js:123 sockjs-client:utils:transport enabled +1ms iframe-eventsource
browser.js:123 sockjs-client:utils:transport enabled +0ms htmlfile
browser.js:123 sockjs-client:utils:transport enabled +1ms iframe-htmlfile
browser.js:123 sockjs-client:utils:transport enabled +1ms xhr-polling
browser.js:123 sockjs-client:utils:transport disabled +1ms xdr-polling
browser.js:123 sockjs-client:utils:transport enabled +1ms iframe-xhr-polling
browser.js:123 sockjs-client:utils:transport enabled +1ms jsonp-polling
...
```

There is lot of logging by sockjs-client mixed with logs by hot realoading and my own console logs. I haven't found any help online.

My `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "template-react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot",
    "build": "webpack --config ./webpack.config.production.js --progress --profile --colors"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2017": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.6",
    "webpack": "^3.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2017",
      "stage-2",
      "react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "react-hot-loader/babel"
    ]
  }
}
```

and `webpack.config.js`

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: {
    'app': [
      'babel-polyfill',
      'react-hot-loader/patch',
      './src/index'
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  resolve : {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    modules: [
        path.resolve('src'),
        path.resolve('static'),
        path.resolve('node_modules')
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          'process.env': {
              NODE_ENV : JSON.stringify('development'),
              BROWSER : JSON.stringify(true)
          }
      }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      { 
        test: /\.jsx|js$/, 
        exclude: /node_modules/, 
        loader: 'babel-loader' 
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: it has nothing to do with your project (config) since these logs didnt show up in your previous computer. Configure your browser console with the same settings as before (previous computer browser console) and you will get the same results you are used to see.

Answer (score 4):

`Sockjs` module from webpack is using `debug` node module for logging to console. Enviroment variable DEBUG (which is used to setup `debug` module) was set to `*` and this was saved in localStorage. So my new project running on `localhost:8080` as some previous project on the same machine used `DEBUG='*'` hence the logging.

I tried to set `process.env.DEBUG` in `webpack.config.js` to some other value but it did not changed value in localStorage so it kept logging. So I just deleted value from localStorage manualy.